# Cloudwatch not parsing multiline logs with multiple JSON objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, asp.net-core-5.0, ilogger

Our API (.Net Core) running in AWS EC2 creates multi-line log entries like this:

```
2021-10-21 15:02:22.968|Error|{
  "Message": "An error has occurred."
}|Product.Api.Exceptions.ApiException: {
  "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
   at Product.Api.Utils.Http.ResponseValidationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\BuildAgent\work\Product.Api\Utils\Http\Response
ValidationHandler.cs:line 26
```

These are fed directly into AWS Cloudwatch but are split into multiple log entries, like this:

```
2021-10-21T15:02:25.123+01:00   2021-10-21 15:02:22.968|Error|{ "Message": "An error has occurred."
2021-10-21T15:02:25.123+01:00   }|Product.Api.Exceptions.ApiException: { "Message": "An error has occurred."
2021-10-21T15:02:25.123+01:00   } at Product.Api.Utils.Http.ResponseValidationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\BuildAgent\work\Product.Api\Utils\Http\Response
```

We then send them directly to DataDog, so we need them correct in Cloudwatch before we do.

If the multiline log was a single valid JSON string I believe it would parse correctly, but because there is a combination of string, JSON and pipes(|) it seems to just split on what it thinks are the separate JSON objects.

Is there anyway to keep it as one log entry in Cloudwatch?

I've seen a lot of solutions, but they all seem to relate to Cloudwatch Insights/Metrics, but we send these logs straight to DataDog, so don't analyse them in Cloudwatch itself.

Comment: How, _exactly_ do the logs get fed into CloudWatch. Are you using an agent or some logging framework that writes directly? If you're using the standard AWS agent, it can be configured to handle multi-line logs. If you're using a third-party agent or logging framework, it may be but we can't help you if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: Are you using API Gateway? EC2? ECS? Fargate? Where is your ASP.NET Core 5 API running?

Comment: Sorry! Web API is running on EC2 :) i don't think we've used anything custom so assume its the standard Cloudwatch agent.

Comment: We don't install the Cloudwatch agent on our EC2 instance explicitly afaik... Would it already be installed we default usually?